# Difference between Thread.sleep() and Object.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, thread-sleep

I have a function:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                myThread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is calling `Thread.sleep(500);` the same as calling `myThread.sleep(500);`?

Are there any differences between the two different calls?

Comment: Other than a way to confuse yourself and others there is no difference. You can make mThread null and it will still do the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> public static void sleep(long millis)
>               throws InterruptedException
> ```
>
> Causes the **currently executing thread** to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

The sleep() method is static. It should always be called as `Thread.sleep()`. Writing `otherThread.sleep()` does *not* cause `otherThread` to sleep; it causes the *current* thread to sleep.

Comment: +1 If you reference it as `myThread.sleep(...)` in Eclipse, it should give you a warning: `The static method sleep(long) from the type Thread should be accessed in a static way`